# FileInput content loaded from server

Tags: php, jquery, file, file-io, input

I use bootstrap file input [plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) to upload thumbs.

i create a page to add a new product info with a thumb and send it to database. Now i want to update a product and change its thumb.

So my question is :

Is there any way to set thumb ( server side ) into file input ? it helps me to decide if i want to update thumb or not when i click to update button.

NB :I use php for .

Thank you.